# Find the maximum value of product given the sum

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partitioning a natural number $n$ in order to get the maximum product sequence of its addends](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125065/partitioning-a-natural-number-n-in-order-to-get-the-maximum-product-sequence-o)

Given

> $a_1+\cdots+a_n=k$

where $a_1$ to $a_n$ natural numbers
what is the maximum number of

> $a_1\times\cdots\times a_n$?

Comment: For a start, look at the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality. Making the variables integers instead of real makes it more interesting.

Comment: Prove that if two of the summands differ by more than $1$ then you can increase the product by making those two summands closer to each other.