# Maximal Multiplication of All Possible Summands

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, optimization

I have recently got interested in the following problem:

> Give a decomposition of a natural number to natural summands whose multiplication is maximal.

I have tried to solve this problem, and have written [this](https://www.scribd.com/doc/253520723/Maximal-Multiplication-of-All-Possible-Summands).

I would like to hear your opinion - is this (mathematical) solution ture? are all my steps leggit?

Also, I was wandering - is this decomposition unique, in a way? For example, we have $3+3+4=3+3+2+2=10$ which gives the same multiplication. I think that this is the only exception from my solution, am I right?

philosophically, is this problem and solution considered very trivial? If so, what similar (harder) problems of this sort are avalibale?

Comment: The problem itself has an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125065/partitioning-a-natural-number-n-in-order-to-get-the-maximum-product-sequence-o). Your argument is unnecessarily complicated, but at a very quick glance it appears to be correct; at any rate the conclusion is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The decomposition problem is fairly straightforward.

Any number $n, n>4$ can be decomposed into $(n-2)$ and $2$ and the product $2n-4 = n + (n-4) > n$. So we should never have any integer greater than $4$ or (trivially) less than $2$ in a maximal-product partition of $n>1$. Decomposing $4$ into $(2,2)$ makes no difference. We can observe that the best decomposition of $6$ is $(3,3)$ not $(4,2)$ and that in general taking factors of $3$ is the best option unless it means leaving $1$.

The underlying reason for this is that $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ has a maximum at $e$, and a maximum in integers at $3$ (with $\frac{\ln 2}{2}=\frac{\ln 4}{4}$).

Nobody here is likely to read through lengthy proofs on another site.