# Given a number N, how to construct a set of different numbers that has a maximal product, and the sum of these numbers equal N?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, computational-geometry

Note that:

1. N is positive integer.
2. The set also consists of positive integers.
3. The set consists of **different** integers. (The thread suggested by @hardmath doesn't have this constraint.)

For example:

if $N = 4$, we can construct the set as ${4}$, and the product is 4.

if $N = 5$, we can construct the set of two elements ${2, 3}$, and their product is 6.

if $N = 7$, we can construct the set of two elements ${3, 4}$, and their product is 12.

if $N = 31$, the set is {2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8}.

How to solve this problem for a general $N$? And how can you prove the correctness of your solution?

Comment: For the version in which summands are required to be positive integers, see the previous Question, [Partitioning a natural number $n$ in order to get a maximum product sequence of its addends](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125065/partitioning-a-natural-number-n-in-order-to-get-the-maximum-product-sequence-o).