# Given $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geqslant 2}$, find the partition $(a_1,...,a_k)\in\mathbb{N}^k:\sum_{i=1}^k a_i=n$ of $n$ that maximizes $\prod_{i=1}^k a_i$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, integer-partitions

I am a solving programming [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/integer-break) in Leetcode in which, given a number $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geqslant 2}$, I have to find $(a_1, ..., a_k) \in \mathbb{N}^k$ such that $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $2 \leqslant k \leqslant n$, $\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i = n$, and $\prod_{i=1}^{k} a_i$ is maximum.

More specifically, given a natural number $n$ greater than $1$, I have to split this number into $k$ natural numbers/partitions $(a_1, ..., a_k)$, where $k$ is greater than $1$ and less than or equals to $n$, the sum of all $a_i$s, for $i$ between $1$ and $k$, results in $n$, and the product of all $a_i$s is maximum.

Let me give you some examples:

- **Example 1**: With $n = 2$, the only partition we can have is $(1, 1)$, since $k \geqslant 2$.
- **Example 2**: With $n = 3$, the only partitions we can have are $(2, 1)$ or $(1, 2)$ (note that the partition values order does not matter), since they satisfy the stated conditions.
- **Example 3**: With $n = 7$, the partitions $(3, 4)$ and $(3, 2, 2)$ give the maximum product ($3 \times 2 \times 2 = 3 \times 4 = 12$), have a number of elements less than or equals to $n$ and greater than 1, and their values sum results in $n$.
- **Example 4**: With $n = 10$, the partitions $(3, 3, 2, 2)$ and $(3, 3, 4)$ give that maximum product ($3 \times 3 \times 2 \times 2 = 3 \times 3 \times 4 = 36$), and satisfy all the stated conditions.

Already exists good algorithms to solve this problem. However, there is one that is used to find the maximum product for this problem in $O(1)$ time complexity. The algorithm is as follows:

1. if $n \leqslant 3$, then return $n - 1$;
2. else if the remainder of $\frac{n}{3}$ is $0$, i.e., $0 \equiv n ($mod $3)$ ($n$ is divisible by $3$), then return $3^{\frac{n}{3}}$
3. else if the remainder of $\frac{n}{3}$ is $1$, i.e., $1 \equiv n ($mod $3)$, then return $4 \times 3^{\frac{n}{3} - 1}$
4. else if the remainder of $\frac{n}{3}$ is $2$, i.e., $2 \equiv n ($mod $3)$, then return $2 \times 3^{\frac{n}{3}}$

This algorithm is used in the programming community to solve this problem. There is an informal correctness proof for this algorithm ([here](https://leetcode.com/problems/integer-break/discuss/80721/Why-factor-2-or-3-The-math-behind-this-problem./85320)) but irrespective of that I am not convinced (and even clueless and doubtful) why this works. Thence, I would like to know if anyone can see some concealed property in the natural numbers $\geqslant 4$ that permits to find the maximum product partition by leveraging its remainder of division by $3$, i.e., what is the motif of using division by $3$. If anyone has any understating regarding the algorithm or sees any flaw/bug in it, please let me know.

For more implementation details ([here](https://leetcode.com/problems/integer-break/discuss/1152124/Java-%2B-Explanation-Smart-O(1)-solution%3A-runs-in-0-ms-(Beats-100))).

I am sorry if any clumsy notation makes mathematicians worrisome, but I am a computer scientist.

Very thank you.

Comment: Cf. this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/125078/602049).

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for (but with k \geqslant 2). I'll check it out and return here ASAP.

Comment: It is not difficult to show the optimum parts must be of size $2,3,4$, and that one part of $4$ is equivalent to two parts of $2$, and that two parts of $3$ are better than three parts of $2$.  So for $n>1$, having zero, one or two parts of $2$ with all the other parts being of $3$ is optimal, (perhaps replacing two parts of $2$ with one part of $4$).  This leads to the algorithm

Comment: @JohnOmielan and #Henry, very thank you for the responses. The https://oeis.org/A000792 was exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: According to a 2020 [paper](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/uproc13/uproc13.Abstract.html) by Schneider and Sills, section 3, this has appeared in problem sets from Newman and Halmos.  They did not find a definitive attribution.

Comment: Very thank you @BrianHopkins, I've found sources regarding this problem, but so far I haven't found any scientific paper with a formal definition and proof about it. I am reading the article you sent me, and now it's much more clear.