# Change in Partition for Geometric Mean if Sum Increases

Tags: integer-partitions

Suppose we have a fixed constant $k$, and a number $x$, where we need to partition $x$ into the sum of $k$ integers: $$x = x_1+\cdots+x_k$$ such that the geometric mean $\prod_{i=1}^k x_i$ is maximized.

If we want to partition $x+1$ into the sum of $k$ integers as well, such that the geometric mean is maximized, is it true that such a partition is simply $x_1, \ldots, (x_i+1), x_k$ for some $i \in [k]$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125065/partitioning-a-natural-number-n-in-order-to-get-the-maximum-product-sequence-o?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Proof:

Assume $\prod x_h$ is maximised, and there exists $i,j$ such $x_i+1\leq x_j-1$ (that is, $x_i$ and $x_j$ differ by at least 2).

Without loss of generality, let $i=1$ and $j=2$.

Let $y_h$ be such that $y_1=x_1+1$, $y_2=x_2-1$, and $y_h=x_h$ for all $h>2$.

Note that $\sum x_h = \sum y_h$, and let $\prod x_h = P$.

It's easy to show that $$\prod y_h = P\left(1+\frac{x_2-x_1-1}{x_1x_2}\right).$$

However, if $x_1+1\leq x_2-1$, then $x_2-x_1-1>0$, so $\prod y_h > P$, contradicting the assumption that $P$ is maximal.

This characterises the solutions to the puzzle: there is some $q$ for which all $x_h$ are either $q$ or $q+1$, specifically, let $x=kq+r$, with $0\leq r<k$, then $r$ of the $x_h$ are $q+1$, and $k-r$ of them are $q$.

If $x=kq+r$, and $x+1=kq^\prime+r^\prime$, then either $r^\prime=r+1$, or $r=k-1$, $r^\prime=0$ and $q^\prime=q+1$. In either of these cases, there is an $x_i$ such that $x_i=q$ and $x^\prime_i=q+1$.

Comment: You took quite some effort to answer the question. Why didn't you upvote the question? It stimulates the OP to put in more questions and makes him feel part of SE. - Sorry to ask you in particular. I just wonder.

Comment: @niloderoock it probably just didn't occur to me. I'm not in the habit of upvoting or downvoting on this site.