# Change in Partition for Weighted Geometric Mean if Sum Increases

Tags: integer-partitions, discrete-optimization

I previously asked a question [Change in Partition for Geometric Mean if Sum Increases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202865/change-in-partition-for-geometric-mean-if-sum-increases/4202878#4202878), to show that if the sum increases by 1, then all we need to do is increase one of the partitions by 1 to increase the geometric mean. I was wondering if this result extends to the weighted geometric mean case.

Running some simulations, it seems that this is true, but can't seem to derive a formal proof for it. I tried the approach by the answer to the unweighted question, but it doesn't simply extend to this case.

Expressing the problem formally:
Suppose we have a fixed constant $k$, and a number $x$, and integer weights $w_1, ..., w_k \geq 1$ where we need to partition $x$ into the sum of $k$ integers: $$x = x_1+\cdots+x_k$$ such that the **weighted** geometric mean $\prod_{i=1}^k x_i^{w_i}$ is maximized.

If we want to partition $x+1$ into the sum of $k$ integers as well, such that the weighted geometric mean is maximized, is it true that such a partition is simply $x_1, \ldots, (x_i+1), x_k$ for some $i \in [k]$?